# REST API - GeoServer (WMS)

Tags: node.js, rest, geolocalização

Boas,

Como posso fazer a integração de dados Georeferenciados entre uma REST API (NodeJS) e um servidor GeoServer para criar um WMS?

Obrigado pelas dicas